# How do I find a specific Java class definitions?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting my hands on an Android application project.  The compiler often complains that it "cannot find symbol class" or variable, because their definition has to be imported explicitely.

E.g. if I need the `File` class I have to `import java.io.File;`.

There are numerous questions on SO asking specifically about a particular class.

But how am I supposed to know in which "metapackage" (i.e. `java.io` in the above example) I can find the class definition ?

I found [a base Java list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/allclasses-noframe.html) and [an Android class index](https://developer.android.com/reference/classes) but it seems quite tedious to go back and forth between both lists and having to click on each class to have the full path.

Bonus question : does Android Studio have a shortcut to help finding them ?

Comment: I don't understand how you have the code but not the import statements - can you give some context?

Comment: Usually, if you hover the class that is not found, a *normal* IDE will list you all packages that contain the class.

Comment: If someone on StackOverflow refers to a `File` class, there's no way to definitively know what they're referring to. Your best bet is just to search for ["java File class"](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+File+class) and hope that the one at the top matches the method signatures they've used.

Comment: @JanLarsen For now I am just copypasting code samples from developer.android.com, and they come without the import statements (at least the ones I'm on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should answer both questions.

You can simply click on the declaration you've made and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will bring up a context menu, with either an "Import..." option or a list of possible imports. Simply use your arrow keys to select the proper one and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to import it.

The menu will tell you the package that class is in, and you won't have to know it beforehand.

Comment: "use your arrow keys to select the proper one" Wasn't his question basically "how do I know which is the proper one?"

Comment: @Michael I don't think so. OP is asking how to know which package a certain class belongs, not which class is the right one. At least, that's how I understood it. It seems to be they're just looking up where these classes belong and importing them manually instead of using the IDE tools.

Comment: @TheWanderer Exactly.  BTW, actually Alt+Enter seems to auto-add the `import` line, at least when there is only one eligible import.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou Oh right. Sorry I don't have access to the IDE right now, and I usually just Tab-complete based on a suggestion to avoid having to import everything.

Comment: Better yet, when moving the cursor there seem to be a blue popup with the  on the closest next undeclared class (which appears as red and underlined) and alt+enter actually adds the suggested import statement.

Answer (score 2):

alt+Enter suggests a list of possible packages.

Answer (score 1):

Place your cursor on the class u wish to import and press ctrl+space and you will get suggestions and just click on the correct option , it will be imported automatically

Refer to below link for all shortcuts in android studio
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts